# URLs ending with no page name

Tags: url, url-rewriting

Thank you for reading my post.

Nowadays, when one visits a Web page in a Web browser, it is very frequent to have URLs with no page names in the navigation bar like for example:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/
```

I'm used to these kind of URLs which end up with page names:

```
http://www.example.com/welcome.html
http://www.example.com/welcome.php
http://www.example.com/welcome.jsp
```

- I'm familiar with HTML.
- My current Website was written in PHP and I'm maintaining it.
- And I'm currently writing Java Webapps (including .jsp files).

In all of these cases, the URLs end with a page name like in the examples above.

So my questions are:

- When a URL doesn't end up with a page name, "where" does it come from?
- Is the developer actually hiding the page names with some mechanism?
- Is it a specific technology which allows to use URLs with no page names?
- Why would one do that? For security reasons?

I hope my questions are clear enough.

Best regards.

Comment: One of the reasons for doing this is for creating more SEO friendly URLs (http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/create-seo-friendly-urls-using-mod-rewrite-and-php-part-1.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I added the tag "url-rewriting". I also removed the tag "php" because this question is not PHP specific (sorry).

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer (Thanks Tim and DarkBee)**

The website will most likely use either Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or IIS [URL Rewrite module.](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

One example where this is massively used today is MVC application pattern.Most MVC apps use a specific kind of routing, it is, by default:

```
website.com/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Which then allows you to address each variable and proccess the request accordingly. The path is only abstract and there is no such folder structure on the server, it just gives the application a certain set of variables upon which it decides what content to display.

More info on MVC is here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: MVC can be used in any programming environment, its just a patern. 
MVC uses mod_rewrite true, but mod_rewrite has nothing to do with MVC

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is not absolutely true either, MVC running on IIS don't use mod_rewrite, but they use IIS specific URL Rewrite module instead.

Comment: True, I should stated MVC in PHP uses mod_rewrite ^^

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is an MVC or not it is url rewriting. In apache it is achieved like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^step-1/?$                           step1.php    [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^step-2/?$                           step2.php    [NC,L]
```

it means that when you click those links you will see step-1 instead of step-1.php and so on.